# Reversing Linked List not resolving firstNode

Tags: java, linked-list

I wrote a Linked List implementation which is headed by firstNode and ends at lastNode. I'm trying to reverse the list which its doing perfectly with the exception of firstNode. Say I have the following pieces of data in the list starting from firstNode going to lastNode: "one", "two", "three", "four", "five". When I run my reverseMePlz() method the following will be displayed: four, three, two, one. The original firstNode (one) is now the lastNode and the original lastNode(five) is not becoming the firstNode but rather two which should be the second node is becoming the firstNode so essentially it's deleting what was originally the lastNode which should be the firstNode. Here is my codE:

```
public void reverseMePlz()
{
    Node nextNode = null;

    Node currentNode = firstNode;

    while (currentNode.next != null)
    {
        nextNode = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = currentNode.previous;

        firstNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;

    }

    lastNode = currentNode;

}
```

Comment: This is a doubly-linked list right?

Comment: Yes it is doubly-linked. Node is a private class inside my list class with the following instance variables: T data, Node next, Node previous.

Comment: But while reversing your not changing the links of your 'previous'

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition of your `while` loop to,

```
while(currentNode!=null)
```

Here is the code,

```
public void reverse(Node headNode) {
        Node nextNode = null;
        Node previousNode = null;
        Node currentNode = headNode;

        while(currentNode!=null) {
            nextNode = currentNode.next;
            currentNode.next = previousNode;
            currentNode.previous = nextNode;
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
        headNode = previousNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This was my solution:

```
public void reverseMePlz()
    {
        Node nextNode = null, currentNode = firstNode, first = firstNode;

        while (currentNode.next != null)
        {
            nextNode = currentNode.next;

            currentNode.next = currentNode.previous;
            currentNode.previous = nextNode;

            firstNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = nextNode;

        }

        lastNode.next = firstNode;
        firstNode = lastNode;
        lastNode = first;
        firstNode.previous = null;

    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured it out. Deleted my answer since I messed up somewhere.